# Cannot call client and server function at the same time in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following button which call a client and a server function:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnOk" runat="server"  OnClick="BtnOk_Click" 
OnClientClick="addUnknownDrivers(event)" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Ok"/>
```

In the first time I had an issue with the addUnknownDrivers() function, it cannot call it, after doing a search I resolved it by setting UseSubmitBehavior to false, so the addUnknownDrivers() function is called.

But after I added event as parameter to the function addUnknownDrivers(event), I didn't call the javascript function.

```
function addUnknownDrivers(evt) {...}
```

Thank you !

Comment: I've tried your code in my local. It works fine!

Comment: Did you add the event parameter? I did that too in a separate example and it works, that's strange !

Comment: You know sometimes error can be about your browser cahce, visual studio etc. So I think delete page and add new page.

Comment: Thank you Mehmed, it works. The code is correct, I think I had a javascript error and I didn't pay attention to it.